# ExtJS Grid not refreshing after store update

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs, gridview

I have a grid and a store. The store gets populated with some data - `country` - while the rest is empty. Once I receive more inputs I fill up the store with the inputs.

Assume that I have only 1 country in the store after the initial load.

Store:

```
feedTheGrid = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoDestroy : true,
    autoSave : false,
    autoLoad : true,
    idProperty: 'country',
    root: 'root',
    totalProperty : 'totalcount',
    fields : ['country', 'towns'],
    proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy(new Ext.data.Connection({
        url : "country/searchCountries.action",
        method : 'POST',
        timeout : 300000
    }))
});
```

So the user inputs towns. I save a town in the array `towns` using `push()`:

```
listeners: {
    'change': function() {
        if (feedTheGrid.getAt(0).towns === undefined) {
            feedTheGrid.getAt(0).towns = [];
        }
        feedTheGrid.getAt(0).towns.push(this.getValue());
        gridMonster.getView().refresh();
    }
}
```

I want the grid to update every time a new town is put in.

This is part of the column model I use for `gridMonster`:

```
{ header: "Town 1", width: 150, dataIndex: 'towns', 
  renderer: function(val) {
      if (val[0] != undefined) {
          return val[0];
      }
  }, sortable: true},
{ header: "Town 2", width: 150, dataIndex: 'towns',
  renderer: function(val) {
      if (val[1] != undefined) {
          return val[1];
      }
  }, sortable: true},  
{ header: "Town 3", width: 150, dataIndex: 'towns',
  renderer: function(val) {
      if (val[2] != undefined) {
          return val[2];
      }
  }, sortable: true}
```

**The issue is that after a town is put in the grid never refreshes.**

Some things I noticed so far:

The store gets updated with the new value when I check through Firebug. Also it seems the val that is given in renderer is always empty String, even after I push the new value into the array and refresh the grid view.

I am using ExtJS 3.3.1

I know its old so I am open to solutions that would work for 4.0+ and I can try to apply it to 3.3.1.

**EDIT: Found the issue**

Very subtle problem, spent hours trying to find what is the problem only to find out I was looking in the wrong place. The issue was in this line:

```
feedTheGrid.getAt(0).towns.push(this.getValue());
```

This line actually creates a new field `towns` as part of the record that you get using `getAt(0)`. Using firebug to see if `getAt(0).towns[0]` is populated actually returns the value you pushed which is misleading.

ExtJS is not aware of this new field and it shouldn't be.

This line should be:

```
feedTheGrid.getAt(0).data.towns.push(this.getValue());
```

The trick is to point at the right place: `.data`. Javascript/ExtJS allows you to add new field without any warning because technically you are not doing anything wrong. Logically it creates a new field that does nothing.

@Lorenz Meyer I am able to display elements of the array using renderer while pointing at towns array in the column model.

Comment: Why do you have 3 columns all containing a town? A grid should have columns that refer each to a field of a record in the store.

Comment: each column is an element of the array.

Comment: I think having multiple columns mapping to the same member (dataIndex) may be a problem. Checked the console for errors ?

Comment: @FrancisDucharme no errors in console. Check edit for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very subtle problem, spent hours trying to find what is the problem only to find out I was looking in the wrong place. The issue was in this line:

```
feedTheGrid.getAt(0).towns.push(this.getValue());
```

This line actually creates a new field towns as part of the record that you get using `getAt(0`). Using firebug to see if `getAt(0).towns[0]` is populated actually returns the value you pushed which is misleading.

ExtJS is not aware of this new field and it shouldn't be.

This line should be:

```
feedTheGrid.getAt(0).data.towns.push(this.getValue());
```

The trick is to point at the right place: `.data`. Javascript/ExtJS allows you to add new field without any warning because technically you are not doing anything wrong. Logically it creates a new field that does nothing.

@Lorenz Meyer I am able to display elements of the array using renderer while pointing at towns array in the column model.

Answer (score 2):

There is a major misunderstanding about what a store and a grid are in ExtJs.

Both are just a representation of tabular data. A `store` is the representation in memory of a table, in order to get fast access to records filtering and more features. A `grid` is the visual representation of a table in the browser window.

Such a table could look like :

```
Id | Country | City
-------------------
1  | US      | NYC
2  | France  | Macon
3  | US      | Macon
```

First of all on one table row, you can only have one city. In tables, you cannot have an array in a single field. If you have more than one city, this is what **rows** are for.

Then, your `idProperty` cannot be the country. If it were, this would mean that countries are unique. Obviously, they aren't. There can be more than one city in a country. (cities cannot be the idProperty neither, because there exists more than one city with the same).

Now you certainly begin to understand, that `feedTheGrid.getAt(0).towns.push(this.getValue());` makes no sense whatever. The `towns` column cannot be an array. You insert a new row with `feedTheGrid.add({country: 'US', towns: 'LA'})`.
At best the `towns` column can be a comma separated value, in which case, you update the store with

```
var record = feedTheGrid.getAt(0),
currentTowns = record.get('towns');
record.set('towns', currentTowns + ', ' + value)
```

The method `set` of the record does all the magic: It passes the update event to the grid in order to rerender it. Your `push` in addition to be wrong will not trigger the events necessary to update the view.

About the grid: The columns of your grid should be:

```
{ header: "Id", width: 150, dataIndex: 'id', sortable: true},
{ header: "Country", width: 150, dataIndex: 'country', sortable: true},  
{ header: "Town(s)", width: 150, dataIndex: 'towns', sortable: true}
```

Notes:

- That `listeners:` looks really strange to me, but maybe it's just because the bigger picture is missing.
- `feedTheGrid` is a strange name for a store. The store does not *feed the data*. It **is** tha data.
- A renderer alway must return a value, else the cell will remain blank. Therefore your renderers cannot work.

Comment: Thanks for the input. As a side note I managed to use an array as data for columns in another grid I made. It picked up values from the array that I specified through the renderer. I am obviously not using countries as unique ID I was attempting to make the problem more generic. Same goes for store/grid names. I am sorry for the confusion. I am aware that the store is the data.

Comment: I unwrapped the array and set up individual fields in store/grid for each town. It still doesn't refresh the grid. The store accepts the new value. I am just doing an assignment using `this.getValue()` from the input.

Answer (score 1):

In your renderers the `val` can not be an array. It's a simple variable. That's why your grid is not refreshing.